# Imprimir elementos con lambda

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda

Me encuentro con un problema relacionado con **lambda**, y es que nunca he usado esta expresión y necesito ayuda ya que tengo que realizar esta práctica con **lambda**.

Os enseño código principal donde se puede ver diferentes elementos (personas) que tengo en un *ArrayList*:

```
public class Check {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
    people.add(new Person("11111-A","David","Garcia",LocalDate.now(),63.2));
    people.add(new Person("14111-A","Elena","Lazaro",LocalDate.now(),60));
    people.add(new Person("13111-A","Marina","Garcia",LocalDate.now(),17.3));
    people.add(new Person("12111-A","Manuel","Garcia",LocalDate.now(),91));
}
```

Ahora bien, mediante un *forEach()* me gustaría imprimir todos aquellas personas que su apellido comience por la letra 'L'. En este caso se imprimiría solamente la persona *Elena Lazaro*.

Tengo que saber como rellenar las paréntesis del siguiente código:

```
people.forEach();
```

¿Puede ser algo similar a esto la expresión lambda?

```
c -> c.getApellidos().charAt(0) == 'L'
```

Debo primero seleccionar aquellos objetos filtrando por la primera letra del apellido y después imprimirlo. El requisito en esta práctica es usar la expresión **lambda**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo dos formas que encontré y probé como eficaces.

Con simplemente tener cada elemento del forEach y hacer la condición de tu ejemplo:

```java
people.forEach(person -> {
            if(person.subSequence(0, 1).equals("L")){
                System.out.println(person);
            }
        });
```

Con métodos únicamente funcionales de Java 8+:

```java
people.stream()
               .filter(person->person.subSequence(0, 1).equals("L"))
               .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Este método, como ves, aplica un filtro según una condición sobre los elementos con una expresión funcional: `person -> {condición}`.

Tenía meses que no usaba Java y nunca usé estos métodos funcionales en este lenguaje... Y ya que los he probado en Javascript y Scala, me parece que no son altamente legibles, por lo menos el `stream()` y la posición del `forEach()` me dan esa impresión.